# How to filter query by current timestamp in a Spring Data repository using PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, utc

I have entities with a `validTill` field of type `Instant`, that is a datetime value in utc, to indicate whether the entity has been soft deleted. I would like to query for all entities, but exclude the soft deleted ones from the result. I tried something like this:

```
@Query(
    "SELECT e " +
    "FROM MyEntity e " +
    "WHERE e.validTill IS NULL OR e.validTill > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
)
Set<MyEntity> findValidMyEntities();
```

However, if my local time is `2022-04-26 10:00:00.000000+03` (meaning utc time is `2022-04-26 07:00:00.000000+00`) and `e.validTill` value is `2022-04-26 08:00:00.000000+00`, the entity is not included in the result, even though `e.validTill` value is after the utc time. Entities with `validTill` after my local time are included in the result. So, I'm quite sure the issue is with the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP being transformed. How can I fix this so that the `e.validTill > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` only uses the utc format values?
I also know I could give the `Instant.now()` value as a parameter to be used instead of current_timestamp, but I would really like to avoid that.

**EDIT a day later**
I have not figured out the solution, but I feel I have come closer, and thought the things I have learned might help somebody.
The problem definetly is with using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. I made sure that in my Spring Boot project application.yml file contains `spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC`. Additionally, I added a script to my version control, so that when the database is created, the db server uses UTC timezone:

```
ALTER DATABASE myDatabase SET TIME ZONE TO 'UTC'
```

I was sure that these changes would solve my problem, but I was wrong. If I make a query for the timezone of my database using `SHOW timezone`, I get the response `UTC`. However, if I make the same query through my API, I get my local timezone as a response. So, I suspect JDBC is the culprit here, and I have not been able to find the solution.